# How to get Json data in android from php file?

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

i am new in android i have created a simple data fetching application.I am fetching two variable from my php file but i am getting value of only one variable.And when i am testing in my browser i am getting both variable value in json.

Code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity{

ArrayList<Person> arrayofWebData = new ArrayList<Person>();

class Person {

    boolean messageReceived;
       public String message;
public String message_recd;
public String message_sent;

}

FancyAdapter aa = null;
static ArrayList<String> resultRow;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    try{
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > 9) {
            StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
            StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        }
        String result = "";

        try{
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://10.0.2.2/progress_card/messages/get_messages.php");
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
            InputStream webs = entity.getContent();

            try{
                 BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(webs, "UTF-8"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
                    sb.append(line+"\n");
                }

                webs.close();
                result = sb.toString();
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error Converting Result "+e.toString());

            }

        }catch(Exception e){
                Log.e("log_tag", "Error Converting Result "+e.toString());

            }

        try{

            JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(result);
            for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
                JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

                Person resultRow = new Person();
                if (json_data.has("message_recd")){
                    resultRow.messageReceived = true;
                    resultRow.message = json_data.getString("message_recd");
                }
                if (json_data.has("message_sent")){
                    resultRow.messageReceived = false;
                    resultRow.message = json_data.getString("message_sent");
                }
                arrayofWebData.add(resultRow);  

               //...
               //aa = new FancyAdapter();


               //...
        }
        }
        catch(JSONException e){
            Log.e("log_tag", "Error Converting Result "+e.toString());
        }

        ListView myListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.myListView);
        aa = new FancyAdapter(this,arrayofWebData);
        myListView.setAdapter(aa);
    }
        catch(Exception e){
        Log.e("log_tag", "Error Converting Result "+e.toString());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
class FancyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Person>{
    FancyAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<Person> list){ 
        super(activity,android.R.layout.simple_expandable_list_item_1,list);
    } 
    public View getView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent){
        Person selectedPerson = getItem(position);
        ViewHolder holder;

        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView,selectedPerson.messageReceived);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } 
        else{ 
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        } 
        holder.populateFrom(selectedPerson);
        return(convertView);
    } 
} 



class ViewHolder{ 
    public TextView message = null;

    ViewHolder(View row,boolean messageReceived){
        if(messageReceived)
             message = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.name);
        else
             message = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.colors);
    } 
    void populateFrom(Person p){
        message.setText(p.message);
    } 
} 
}
```

Logcat:

```
    10-02 08:27:05.611: E/AndroidRuntime(2045): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-02 08:27:05.611: E/AndroidRuntime(2045): Process: com.shirish.hello, PID: 2045
10-02 08:27:05.611: E/AndroidRuntime(2045): java.lang.NullPointerException
10-02 08:27:05.611: E/AndroidRuntime(2045):     at com.shirish.hello.MainActivity$ViewHolder.populateFrom(MainActivity.java:153)
10-02 08:27:05.611: E/AndroidRuntime(2045):     at com.shirish.hello.MainActivity$FancyAdapter.getView(MainActivity.java:136)
10-02 08:27:05.611: E/AndroidRuntime(2045):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2255)
10-02 08:27:05.611: E/AndroidRuntime(2045):     at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1790)
10-02 08:27:05.611: E/AndroidRuntime(2045):     at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:691)
10-02 08:27:05.611: E/AndroidRuntime(2045):     at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:752)
10-02 08:27:05.611: E/AndroidRuntime(2045):     at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1630)
10-02 08:27:05.611: E/AndroidRuntime(2045):     at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:2087)
10-02 08:27:05.611: E/AndroidRuntime(2045):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
10-02 08:27:05.611: E/AndroidRuntime(2045):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
10-02 08:27:05.611: E/AndroidRuntime(2045):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1671)
10-02 08:27:05.611: E/AndroidRuntime(2045):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1525)
10-02 08:27:05.611: E/AndroidRuntime(2045):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1434)
10-02 08:27:05.611: E/AndroidRuntime(2045):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
10-02 08:27:05.611: E/AndroidRuntime(2045):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
10-02 08:27:05.611: E/AndroidRuntime(2045):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
10-02 08:27:05.611: E/AndroidRuntime(2045):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
10-02 08:27:05.611: E/AndroidRuntime(2045):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
10-02 08:27:05.611: E/AndroidRuntime(2045):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
10-02 08:27:05.611: E/AndroidRuntime(2045):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:374)
10-02 08:27:05.611: E/AndroidRuntime(2045):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
10-02 08:27:05.611: E/AndroidRuntime(2045):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
10-02 08:27:05.611: E/AndroidRuntime(2045):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:453)
10-02 08:27:05.611: E/AndroidRuntime(2045):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:388)
10-02 08:27:05.611: E/AndroidRuntime(2045):     at android.view.View.layout(View.java:14817)
10-02 08:27:05.611: E/AndroidRuntime(2045):     at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4631)
10-02 08:27:05.611: E/AndroidRuntime(2045):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:1983)
10-02 08:27:05.611: E/AndroidRuntime(2045):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1740)
10-02 08:27:05.611: E/AndroidRuntime(2045):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:996)
10-02 08:27:05.611: E/AndroidRuntime(2045):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5600)
10-02 08:27:05.611: E/AndroidRuntime(2045):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
10-02 08:27:05.611: E/AndroidRuntime(2045):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
10-02 08:27:05.611: E/AndroidRuntime(2045):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
10-02 08:27:05.611: E/AndroidRuntime(2045):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
10-02 08:27:05.611: E/AndroidRuntime(2045):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
10-02 08:27:05.611: E/AndroidRuntime(2045):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-02 08:27:05.611: E/AndroidRuntime(2045):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
10-02 08:27:05.611: E/AndroidRuntime(2045):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
10-02 08:27:05.611: E/AndroidRuntime(2045):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-02 08:27:05.611: E/AndroidRuntime(2045):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-02 08:27:05.611: E/AndroidRuntime(2045):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
10-02 08:27:05.611: E/AndroidRuntime(2045):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
10-02 08:27:05.611: E/AndroidRuntime(2045):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Json Response in browser:

```
[{"message_recd":"checking"},{"message_recd":"qwerty"},{"message_recd":"checking"},{"message_recd":"qw,nsbdf"},{"message_recd":"rtr"},{"message_recd":"QSDWFDWDF"},{"message_recd":"as"},{"message_recd":"sdad"},{"message_recd":"checking12345"},{"message_sent":"hey whtas up"},{"message_sent":"hey whtas up hey whtas "},{"message_sent":"hey whtas up test"},{"message_sent":"hey whtas up11"}]
```

My php code:

```
    <?php

  error_reporting(0);
  define('HOST','localhost');
  define('USER','root');
  define('PASS','');
  define('DB','progress_card');
  $con = mysqli_connect(HOST,USER,PASS,DB);


  $req_dump = print_r($_POST, TRUE);    
    $fp = fopen('request.txt', 'a');
    fwrite($fp, $req_dump);
    fclose($fp);

  //$username = $_POST['username'];
  $sql1 = "select * from student_detail where parentusername='suyash1'";//username = suyash1
  $res1 = mysqli_query($con,$sql1);

  $row1=mysqli_fetch_array($res1);

  $cl=$row1['class']."-".$row1['section'];
  $sql2="select * from teachers where classassign='$cl'";
  $res2 = mysqli_query($con,$sql2);

  $row2=mysqli_fetch_array($res2);

   $to=$row2['email'];
   $from=$row1['parentemail'];

  $result = array();

$sql = "select * from messages where (to_email='".$to."' and from_email='".$from."') OR (from_email='".$to."' and to_email='".$from."') ORDER BY post_date asc";
$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{
    if($row['to_email']==$to)
        array_push($result,array('message_recd'=>$row['message']));
    else if($row['to_email']==$from)
        array_push($result,array('message_sent'=>$row['message']));

}


  /*$sql = "select * from messages where to_email='".$to."' and from_email='".$from."' ORDER BY post_date asc";
  $res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);

  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
    {
    array_push($result,array('message_recd'=>$row['message']));
    }

    $sqlw = "select * from messages where from_email='".$to."' and to_email='".$from."' ORDER BY post_date asc";
    $resw = mysqli_query($con,$sqlw);

    while($row5 = mysqli_fetch_array($resw))
    {

    array_push($result,array('message_sent'=>$row5['message']));
    }*/
    if(mysqli_query($con,$sql))
    {
       // echo 'success';
      }
      else
      {
        //echo 'failure';
      }
    //array_push($result,array('message_sent'=>"dfdsghdfgddfgdsd"));
    //array_push($result,array('message_sent'=>"sfdsflkufhskfhdskjfsfssadfadsffsafasfsfsadfafsaf"));

    //array_push($result,array('message_recd'=>$row1['parentemail'],'message_sent'=>$row2['email']));



//print_r($ress);
    echo json_encode($result);

    mysqli_close($con);

    ?>
```

Comment: Your json object has either message_sent or message_recd.. And you are always checking for both. The error says that your object doesnt have message_sent which is true {"message_recd":"checking"}. You need to check if message_sent exsits in json using json.has("message_sent")

Comment: i want to print both values message_recd as well as message_sent, is it possible?

Comment: check my answer for better solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made some changes on your code, but you have also to get the data inside an asynctask

```
class Person { 

   boolean messageReceived;
   public String message;

} 
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
///...
   for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
        JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

        Person resultRow = new Person();
        if (json_data.has("message_recd")){
            resultRow.messageReceived = true;
            resultRow.message = json_data.getString("message_recd");
        }
        else if (json_data.has("message_sent")){
            resultRow.messageReceived = false;
            resultRow.message = json_data.getString("message_sent");
        }
        arrayofWebData.add(resultRow);  

       //...
       //aa = new FancyAdapter();
       aa = new FancyAdapter(this,arrayofWebData);

       //...
}

class FancyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Person>{
    FancyAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<Person> list){ 
        super(activity,R.layout.row,list);
    } 
    public View getView(int position,View convertView,ViewGroup parent){
        Person selectedPerson = getItem(position);
        ViewHolder holder;

        if(convertView == null){
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } 
        else{ 
            holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
        } 
        holder.populateFrom(selectedPerson);
        return(convertView);
    } 
} 



class ViewHolder{ 
    public TextView messageReceived = null;
    public TextView messageSend = null;

    ViewHolder(View row){
        messageReceived = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.name);
        messageSend = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.colors);
    } 
    void populateFrom(Person p){
        if(p!=null && message !=null){
            if(p.messageReceived){
                messageReceived.setText(p.message);
                messageSend.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }else{
                messageSend.setText(p.message);
                messageReceived.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
            message.setText(p.message);
        }
    } 
}
```

**PHP part**

i believe you have your timestamp column named as timestamp

change that

```
$sql = "select * from messages where to_email='".$to."' and from_email='".$from."'";
$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{
    array_push($result,array('message_recd'=>$row['message']));
}

$sqlw = "select * from messages where from_email='".$to."' and to_email='".$from."'";
$resw = mysqli_query($con,$sqlw);
while($row5 = mysqli_fetch_array($resw))
{
    array_push($result,array('message_sent'=>$row5['message']));
}
```

with that

```
$sql = "select * from messages where (to_email='".$to."' and from_email='".$from."') OR (from_email='".$to."' and to_email='".$from."') ORDER BY timestamp";
$res = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($res))
{
    if($row['to_email']==$to)
        array_push($result,array('message_recd'=>$row['message']));
    else if($row['to_email']==$from)
        array_push($result,array('message_sent'=>$row['message']));

}
```

Comment: I am getting error in last  "message.setText(p)"->(The method setText(CharSequence) in the type TextView is not applicable for the arguments (MainActivity.Person))

Comment: my bad             message.setText(p.message);

Comment: the application is crashing by doing this

Comment: i made a change to adapter constructor

Comment: messageRecieved cannot be resolved or is not a field inside for loop ,

Comment: on for loop i wrote it recieved not received , edit that spell mistake and try again

Comment: Its again crashed on same lines

Comment: do you want to update your code(and error), so i can see what you are testing?

Comment: can you check the R.layout.row xml that you have the ids name and color to textviews?

Comment: sorry i didnt change the ids but  but i am not getting the result the way i want.......i have used two textview and i want them to come after one another but when ever database is updated i am getting values of "message_recd" on top and "message_sent" values on bottom....

Comment: ok i understand, i added an else inside the for, also i have changed a little the populateFrom function

Comment: No change "message_recd"  value is still goin up and "message_sent" value is coming down,,,,,,,instead of taking two Textviews if we take only one than will it be possible to come one another?

Comment: i hope this is my last edit, please check again.. :/

Comment: i didn't understand your last question

Comment: ok let me explain i am doing ,there are two values "message_recd" and "message_sent" ,,,i am displaying them as  a chat layout left and right and when ever any value is updated it should come on bottom.

Comment: but here when ever "message_recd" value is updated its coming on top instead of down

Comment: the messages are displayed as you send them from db with the php. Do you keep any timestamp value with the message?

Comment: No i am not using time stamp values

Comment: you have to use, so you will know the order of the messages.

Comment: I have used time stamp now data is having date and time value, should i have to use in my code also to fetch data like i want?

Comment: i added a php part, check that also

Comment: I have updated the php code but now i am getting blank white screen

Comment: are you sure that there is timestamp column? to run the order by

Comment: i am using post_date as column name and also writing post_date in php file

Comment: but you updated here like that 
 $sql = "select * from messages where (to_email='".$to."' and from_email='".$from."') OR (from_email='".$to."' and to_email='".$from."') ORDER BY timestamp";


change the order by...

Comment: I have updated the php code and u can see what i am using

Comment: Thanks a lot man ,,,it finally worked Thank You Very Much ,You Saved My life

Comment: only approve as i can see not upvote..but maybe someone else downvoted me so... it is ok

Comment: I need atleast 15 reputation for upvote :( but wait i will still do it

Answer (score 0):

Try to check if the json attribute exists before getting its value. Replace the below code to something similar

```
for(int i=0;i<jArray.length();i++){
        JSONObject json_data = jArray.getJSONObject(i);

        Person resultRow = new Person();
        if (json_data.has("message_recd")){
            resultRow.message_recd = json_data.getString("message_recd");
        }
        if (json_data.has("message_sent")){
            resultRow.message_sent = json_data.getString("message_sent");
        }
        arrayofWebData.add(resultRow);  

       //rest of the code
```

Comment: I have used your code but i am not getting the result the way i want.......i have used two textview and i want them to come after one another but when ever database is updated i am getting values of "message_recd" on top and "message_sent" values on bottom....